# jquery .show not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The following code doesn't seem to execute properly for me, and I'm puzzled as to why.  `NonITView` and `ITView` are both divs in my ASP page.  `txtIsIT` is an `asp:textbox` on the page that gets either "yes" or "no" on page load.

```
        if (document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value = "yes") {
            $("#NonITView").hide("slow");
            $("#ITView").show("slow");
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value = "no") {
            $("#ITView").hide("slow");
            $("#NonITView").show("slow");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error");
        }
```

The `if` is evaluating properly.  In firefox's web console, by entering the jquery .show/.hide functions, the divs are properly shown/hidden, which is part of what's confusing me.  Anything sticking out to you that should be fixed?

Comment: there is an error in your if statement, it should be has only one = it should be ==

Comment: try to put that in document ready part and also if you are using jquery use $("#<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").val() instead of document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value and you should use == instead of =.

Comment: You can not change the code with the update solutions because that way you make them looks like wrong. If you like just make some comments on them.

Comment: Why are you using document.getElementById when you are clearly using jQuery as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem.  When an `UpdatePanel` reloads, it restores the attributes of it's contents to their default state, which in this case was `style="display:none"` on both divs.  The code would run, show the appropriate div, then immediately hide it again, because later on in the function I was telling it to fire the `UpdatePanel`'s postback trigger.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

bug at the `=` on both lines, you make them equal, you not check them.

```
document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value = "yes"
```

a Tip, to avoid this kind of bugs write them reverse, as

```
if( "yes" == document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value) {}
```

that way, if by accident write `=` it will throw an error.

Comment: Fixed the `=` and swapped the `document...` for jquery.  updated conditions look like `("yes" == $("#<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").val())`.  show/hide still not working.

Comment: @Crimius Check the html rendered code to see how this javascript is written, do you get any errors ? Are the ids rendered correctly ?

Comment: The rendered code checks out.  Div id's are as written, as is the javascript.  No errors or warning pop up while loading my page or executing code.

Answer (score 1):

In the if statement, you're doing an assignment.

```
document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value = "yes"
```

This will always evaluated to true. So change that line to be:

```
if(document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value === "yes")
```

Also note the three equals signs. It is common practice now for equality to use ===. See this article on why:

[Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this...

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#Button_ID').click(function() {
        if ($("#<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").val() == "yes") {
            $("#NonITView").hide("slow");
            $("#ITView").show("slow");
        }
        else if ($("#<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").val() == "no") {
            $("#ITView").hide("slow");
            $("#NonITView").show("slow");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error");
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that this is in a function being fired off of a button click.

Comment: aha in that case even easier, you can call it from JQuery .click() action which you can set for particular button. I just update my code...

Answer (score 0):

```
(document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value = "yes")
```

should be

```
(document.getElementById("<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").value == "yes")
```

on if statements it should be `==`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing jQuery and regular javascript. If you are going to use jQuery stick with it:

```
if ($("#<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").val() == "yes") {
  $("#NonITView").hide("slow");
  $("#ITView").show("slow");
}
else if ($("#<%= txtIsIT.ClientID %>").val() == "no") {
  $("#ITView").hide("slow");
  $("#NonITView").show("slow");
}
else {
  alert("Error");
}
```

Comment: small note you have to add "#" into selector part because JQuery is not aware of your id otherwise.

Comment: It's because the OP is using Web Forms. Due to the nature of View State you sometimes need to use ClientID to get the proper ID.